# Entity Framework - How to map a required property on one side with no navigation property on other side

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following two POCOs (`Product` and `User`) and a complex type (`Tracking`).

```
class Product() {

    Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    Tracking TrackingInfo { get; protected set; }

    // Some other properties
}


class User() {

    Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    // Some other properties
}


class Tracking() {

      User CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
      Guid CreatedById { get; protected set; }

      // Some other properties
}
```

The tracking class is a wrapper for tracking info and contains other tracking properties (date created, updated etc) and fulfils an interface for other purposes, but for now what I am concerned with is mapping the relationships between the Product `TrackingInfo` and the `User`.

Every `Product` must have an associated `User` which maps to the `TrackingInfo.CreatedBy` property.

The catch is that I don't want to create navigation properties on the User back to the Product - i.e. I don't want to have an `ICollection<Product> ProductsCreated` property.

I'm not sure how the relationship or the complex type mapping should be done in EntityFramework Code First.  I have a mapping class as follows:

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
         this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("Id");

         // Complex type mapping here?
    }

}
```

How can I

1. Map the TrackingInfo complex type
2. Map the CreatedBy -> User single direction relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex types cannot contain navigation properties.  I recommend creating an abstract base class containing the `Tracking` properties as well as for its configuration:

```
public abstract class Tracking
{
    public Guid CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TrackingConfig<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T: Tracking
{
    public TrackingConfig()
    {
        HasRequired( t => t.CreatedBy )
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey( t => t.CreatedById );
    }
}

public class Product : Tracking
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProductConfig : TrackingConfig<Product>
{
    public ProductConfig()
    {
    }
}
```

...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add( new ProductConfig() );
```

Comment: That seems like a sensible solution.  My POCOs already inherit from a base class so refactoring will be straightforward.

Does seem to be a small drawback of EF that complex properties can't contain navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the navigation properties, just don't define them:

```
public ProductMap()
{
    this.HasRequired(p => p.Tracking)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.TrackingId);
}
```

This way you will have access to the user of a product through `Tracking`, but you can't get the products from a user because there is no navigation property to `Product` defined in `Tracking`.